# Cannot import kotlin.test to use assertFailsWith

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, kotlin

For my unit tests, I need to import kotlin.test to be able to use assertFailsWith.

I believe I have the right files in my app build.grade file. Part of the file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    // ----
    // Per https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests
    //
    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Robolectric environment
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    // ----


    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With an Android project and JUnit tests, you need to use the [`kotlin-test-junit`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-test-junit) module rather than `kotlin-test-common` or `kotlin-test-annotations-common` – those are suitable for code shared between platforms in multiplatform projects and are ignored in JVM/Android modules.

Replace the two dependencies with this one:

```
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
```

Comment: I had to use `androidTestImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlinVersion"` instead of `testImplementation` because I wanted to use assertFailsWith in instrumented tests.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but please see the [Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/jvm-test-using-junit.html#add-the-code-to-test-it) on how to set-up *Jetbrains Kotlin Test JUnit* on `Intellij` using *Kotlin DSL*.

Using this approach you need to do the following on `Android Studio`:

**Step 1 - Add this line to your dependencies:** i.e. inside `build.gradle.kts` **`(app-level)`** file

```
dependencies { 
...

testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
...

}
```

**Step 2 (Optional)- Add the test task block** i.e. inside `build.gradle(.kts)` **`(project-level)`** file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration ...

    plugins {
        id("com.android.application") apply false
        ....
    }
    
    // add this block on project-level build.gradle.kts
    tasks.withType<Test> {

        useJUnitPlatform()

    }
```

Otherwise, [@hotkey's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2196460/hotkey) approach should work fine even without even using `androidTestImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlinVersion")`

I tried it using `Kotlin version 1.9.10` and it worked!

I just added this dependendency:

```
testImplementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.9.10")
```

Then I used **`assertFailsWith`** assertion and it worked just fine:

```
class TextExample {

  @Test
    fun  exampleTest(){
        
    
      assertFailsWith<ArithmeticException> { 1 / 0 }
    }
}
```

Let me know how it goes.